# DIJIT | how to change overlay background

Tags: overlay, dojo

I've two dijit dialogs on one page. One is to have black overlay and other is to have white.
HTML is :

```
<div id="test" title="Colorful" dojoType="dijit.Dialog">
content
</div>
```

As per dijit expected behaviour, it should give following code

```
<div dojoattachpoint="node" class="dijitDialogUnderlay _underlay" id="test_underlay"></div>
```

in which, by using ID **test_underlay**, we can customize overlay background. But in my case, I'm getting below code on run time.

```
<div id="dijit_DialogUnderlay_0" class="dijitDialogUnderlayWrapper" widgetid="dijit_DialogUnderlay_0" style="display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;"><div dojoattachpoint="node" class="dijitDialogUnderlay" style="width: 1424px; height: 466px;"></div></div>
```

Any idea why this is happening??
My dojo version is 1.2

Comment: What do you mean "as per digit expected behavior" ?

Comment: Expected behavior means dijit add a ID with a prefix of IDname + "_underlay" on runtime the overlay node depending upon the ID of dijit.Dialog.
Eg: ID test
<div id="test" title="Colorful" dojoType="dijit.Dialog">  

and Code for respective overlay with id "test_underlay"
<div dojoattachpoint="node" class="dijitDialogUnderlay _underlay" id="test_underlay"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Set the background colour of the dijitDialogUnderlay class in your css. And if for some reason you're loading the dojo css before your css, you can add !important.

```
.dijitDialogUnderlay.white_underlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF !important;
}

.dijitDialogUnderlay.black_underlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000 !important;
}
```

In your markup:

```
<div id="test" title="Colorful" dojoType="dijit.Dialog" class="black">content</div>
<div id="test" title="Colorful" dojoType="dijit.Dialog" class="white">content</div>
```

Comment: this will apply to all overlay's background and make them black. Hence it won't serve my purpose as I need one overlay in black and one in white.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var underlay = dijit._underlay;

        dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

                    if(!underlay){
                         underlay = dijit._underlay = new dijit.DialogUnderlay();
            }

            var whiteDialog = dijit.byId("test");
            var blackDialog = dijit.byId("test2");
            dojo.connect(btn1, "onClick", function(e){ whiteDialog.show(); });
            dojo.connect(btn2, "onClick", function(e){ blackDialog.show(); });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

        <div jsId="btn1" dojoType="dijit.form.Button">Show white dialog</div>
        <div jsId="btn2" dojoType="dijit.form.Button">Show black dialog</div>
        <div id="test" title="White" dojoType="dijit.Dialog">
            content
            <script type="dojo/connect" event="onShow">
                dojo.style(underlay.domNode.firstChild, "backgroundColor", "white");
            </script>
        </div>
        <div id="test2" title="Black" dojoType="dijit.Dialog">
            content
            <script type="dojo/connect" event="onShow">
                dojo.style(underlay.domNode.firstChild, "backgroundColor", "black");
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Philippe, said code is not customizing the overlay background at all. My default color for class "dijitDialogUnderlay" is black and it's giving black overlay on both buttons.